# Why does my application crash when loading an array from NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to load an array from the `NSUserDefaults` in an `iPhone` application.  I set things up with this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.myarray_1 = nil;
```

but then my application crashes at the following line:

```
self.myarray_1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                   initWithArray: [defaults objectForKey:@"highscores"]];
```

with the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796c710'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: In addition to what Bjorn points out, you're leaking an NSArray in your assignment to `self.myarray_1`.  Don't allocate an array there, but use `-arrayWithArray:` to get an autoreleased instance back.  Also `myarray_1` doesn't follow standard Cocoa naming conventions.  May I suggest using something like `highScoresArray` or just `highScores`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that an instance of `NSString` received a `count` message, but obviously it does not respond to it (i.e. does not implement such a message). Most likely the message was intended for an `NSArray` instance.

Did you accidentally save an `NSString` instead of an `NSArray` in your defaults for the key `@"highscores"`? Maybe in one of your previous builds? To clear all user defaults, you could just delete the app from the simulator or your device and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.myarray_1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray*)[defaults objectForKey:@"highscores"]];
```

and I am sure you have made variable myarray_1 as proparty of your this class.

Answer (score 0):

The value in your app's defaults is a String, not an Array.  You are probably setting the default to a string rather than an array elsewhere in your code.  Look for where you're calling `-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]` with the `highscores` key as the second parameter.  Either you are still passing in an NSString as the first argument, or you were at one point and it's still set in the app's preferences.